# PHP: Best way to redirect a nonexistent url?

Tags: php, url, redirect

I have a site I'm working on with a /landing-page/ folder, and I'll be making a number of landing pages. I'd like to be able to put urls that have `/lp/` instead of `/landing-page/` in advertisements, and have any url with `/lp/` in it replaced with `/landing-page/`.

Thus:
www.site.com/lp/ipad-inspections
would automatically redirect to:
www.site.com/landing-page/ipad-inspections

I would like to do this without having a `/lp/` folder and a second page corresponding to each landing page. My thought is to have the 404 page check the url and redirect, but I can't seem to get the following to work:

```
<?php /* Automatic redirect for landing pages */
$current_loc = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$short_lp = '/lp/';
$long_lp = '/landing-page/';
if (strpos($current_loc, $short_lp)) {
    $current_loc = str_replace($short_lp, $long_lp, $current_loc, 1);
    header("location: ".$current_loc);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here, that my page is coming up blank? I have narrowed it down to the first line in my `if` statement, which is crashing my page.

If there a better way to do this with apache? Some line I can put in htaccess, maybe?

Comment: I think `.htaccess` would be a better approach than PHP.

Comment: assuming apache, i think you'd be much better served to do this with .htaccess instead of php

Comment: Have you looked at using .htaccess for routing?

Comment: Three people say htaccess, but none of you have a line I can put in htaccess to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RedirectPermanent /lp /landing-page
```

in your .htaccess should do the trick. Best to do this sort of unconditional redirect BEFORE it reaches the PHP stage. It's essentially a "free" operation in Apache, and saves your server the whole parse/compile/execute PHP stages.

Comment: Thanks! I have it as `redirect 301 /lp/ /landing-page/` now, which does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it as you've done it but include the 301 permanently moved header.

```
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header ('Location: '.$location);
```

Also try referencing your URL absolutely, so as to include http://www.domain.com/

**Update**

If you want to redirect with htaccess try

```
redirect 301 /lp/landing-page/ http://www.domain.com/new.html
```